# How to specify path to ld.exe for g++ command without depending on os's search path or any environment variable?

Tags: c++, g++, ld, clang++

I just wonder if there is a way to issue a "one-line" `g++` command with some parameters in order to specify the location of `ld.exe` without depending on **anything else** ever?

Because without OS's search path, `g++` keeps complaining that it just can't find the `ld.exe` lying on the same folder of the `g++` being called!!

Comment: Did you attempt to read [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)? *"-Bprefix
 This option specifies where to find the executables, libraries, include files, and data files of the compiler itself."*.

Answer (score 0):

As @kaylum mentioned [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) in the comment. The `g++` parameter `-B`

```
-B <path to ld.exe>
```

works like charms.